# Как сделать ripple drawable только на Lollipop?

Tags: android

Имеется приложение с minSdk равным 14. Необходимо сделать, чтобы для некоторых элементов на устройствах с Lollipop использовался ripple drawable, а на устройствах с более ранними версиями ОС использовался свой селектор. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам понадобится отдельная папка для разметок для Lollipop.

> res/layout-v21

В неё помещаете разметки, которые будут использоваться для версий >=21

Comment: А не получится ли это как-то сделать через attr? С двумя почти одинаковыми layout вариант неудобный...

Comment: @BArtWell, а как вы используете rippl drawable? Если это xml файлы в папке drawable, то можно их тоже поместить в res/drawable-v21

Comment: да, такой вариант в принципе мне подходит. Но тогда получается не очень красиво: фон для старых ОС является селектором и назван соответственно (selector_main_background.xml), а ripple селектором не является и, как следствие имеет другое имя. Может быть можно как-то через attr привести их к общему имени атрибута?

Comment: Если и селектор и риппл назначаются одинаково (через атрибут android:background) - то можно назвать их одинаковыми именами, поместить в разные папки и они будут выбираться относительно версии ОС.

Comment: Это да. А есть ли возможность не называть их одинаковыми именами, а привести к одинаковому имени с помощью attr и потом уже именно значение из attr использовать в android:background?

Comment: Можно. Но тогда, боюсь, вам понадобятся разные темы/ разные папки values... Т.е. полюбому надо разделять, т.к. ресурсы статичны и не могут програмно меняться.